# Structure JSON output with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I am trying to generate a JSON output from the DATABASE with MySQL.
The result that I want is that I want an array around two matching ID's found in the tabel in the database.

To visualise what I wish to achieve here is my code:

This is my query

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `flower_garden` WHERE `id_flower` IN (0, 1)";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($record = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rows[] = $record;     
}

print json_encode($rows);
```

This is the JSON result I wish to achieve:
(What I want)

```
    [
      [
          "id": "1",
          "id_flower": "3",
          "Title": "rose",
          "Price": 1.25,
          "Number": 15
        },
        {
          "id": "2",
          "id_flower": "3",
          "Title": "daisy",
          "Price": 0.75,
          "Number": 25
        }
      ],
      [
        {
          "id": "3",
          "id_flower": "6",
          "Title": "rose",
          "Price": 1.25,
          "Number": 15
        },
        {
          "id": "4",
          "id_flower": "6",
          "Title": "daisy",
          "Price": 0.75,
          "Number": 25
        }
      ]
    ]
```

Visual result:

[image: what i want]

So, I want the matching ID's (in this case id_flower) put in one array.
This is the result I get:
(What I get)

```
[
  [
      "id": "1",
      "id_flower": "3",
      "Title": "rose",
      "Price": 1.25,
      "Number": 15
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "id_flower": "3",
      "Title": "daisy",
      "Price": 0.75,
      "Number": 25
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "id_flower": "6",
      "Title": "rose",
      "Price": 1.25,
      "Number": 15
    },
    {
      "id": "4",
      "id_flower": "6",
      "Title": "daisy",
      "Price": 0.75,
      "Number": 25
    }
  ]
]
```

Visual result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    foreach ($rows as $key => $val) {

        $return[$val['id_flower']][] = $val;
    }
    echo json_encode($return);
```

Please note I have not tested it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `flower_garden` WHERE `id_flower` IN (0, 1)";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$rows = array();
while($record = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    array_push($rows[$record["id_flower"]], $record);
}
$result = array();
foreach($rows as $k => $v){
    array_push($result, $v);
}
echo json_encode($result);
```

test yourself !